# Running functions on the GPU with swift

Tags: swift, metal

I have a function that can run a long time processing a job (has several inner-loops). I assume that running this on the GPU instead of the CPU will be faster?

Is there a way to run arbitrary functions on the GPU?

Apple has stated that Metal:

> Metal 2 provides near-direct access to the graphics processing unit (GPU), **enabling you to maximize** the... **compute potential** of your apps

I see examples using Metal for gaming and graphics rendering, but are there any examples or links to help me with just running regular functions?

Comment: Your assumption is not entirely correct.

Comment: "arbitrary functions"? No. See Ken's answer below. You have to write custom code for Metal, using only the APIs they provide. This is not trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GPU can be useful for certain kinds of pure computation.

The task must be highly parallelizable.

It must not require any APIs from the system libraries or frameworks. Metal has its own library that only has computation features. No disk access. No data structures beyond arrays/buffers.

There's an upper limit on how long the system will allow a compute shader to run (because it could be an infinite loop with no other way to stop it). So, depending on what you mean by "long time processing", it might not be suitable, or would only be suitable if broken up into chunks of work.

If a task is suitable for the GPU, it has to be explicitly programmed for the GPU. You can't just migrate normal code to the GPU transparently or automatically. It will have to be rewritten.

Comment: In addition to the things Ken outlines in his excellent answer (voted), the GPU is really only suited for SIMD problems (Single Instruction, Multiple Data) where you run the same instruction stream on all the compute units in lock-step, but each compute unit operates on different data. Applying a transformation matrix to a bunch of vertexes is a good example of such an operation.

Comment: And the "upper limit on how long the system will allow a compute shader to run" is less than a second for individual loops, as far as I've been able to establish. (And about 10 seconds for the shader as a whole.)